# Lumen role middleware missing argument

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware, lumen

I'm new to Lumen and i am trying to get the role middleware to work from an example in the Lumen docs:
http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/middleware#middleware-parameters

But as soon as i add the middleware to the route like so:

```
$app->get('/', ['middleware' => 'role:editor', 'uses' => 'IndexController@index']);
```

I get the error:

```
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\{closure}('2', 'Missing argument 3 for App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::handle()', '/Users/peter/app/Http/Middleware/RoleMiddleware.php', '17', array('request' => object(Request), 'next' => object(Closure))) in RoleMiddleware.php line 17
```

When i remove the middle ware everything works as expected

```
$app->get('/', ['uses' => 'IndexController@index']);
```

In app.php:

```
$app->middleware([
    Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    Laravel\Lumen\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class
]);
```

App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class RoleMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role) // <-line 17
    {
        if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
            // Redirect...
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help

Comment: show the RoleMiddleware class

Comment: Added the RoleMiddleware class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you have to register the Middleware as RouteMiddleware so instead of:

```
$app->middleware([
    Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    Laravel\Lumen\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class
]);
```

it has to be:

```
$app->middleware([
    Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    Laravel\Lumen\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
]);

$app->routeMiddleware([
    "role" => App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class
]);
```

Then it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

By the error I understand that you are not providing a parameter in your `handle()` i.e. the 3rd argument.

Your `handle()` should look like this.

`public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)`

The third parameter `$role` stores the value `editor` as per your code

Comment: The strange thing is that its exactly the same "public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)"